# How to find "missing" rows in a Heroku Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I keep getting emails that state the following:

"[Your database X] contains 16,919 rows, exceeding the  plan limit of 10,000. INSERT privileges to the database will be automatically revoked in 7 days. This will cause service failures in most applications dependent on this database."

Even though I have limited the number of rows in my single table application to max 10 000, usually hovering at 9999.

I have checked the number of rows and the number of tables by psql and PGAdmin3.

Any idea how Heroku counts the number of rows in a database? Is this a platform bug or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems like Heroku counts dead rows. Can you try to VACUUM FULL your database?

Comment: Thanks mvp, but doesn't look like that's it... `ANALYZE VERBOSE listener_stats;
INFO:  analyzing "public.listener_stats"
INFO:  "listener_stats": scanned 1209 of 1209 pages, containing 5000 live rows and 1 dead rows; 5000 rows in sample, 5000 estimated total rows` P.S. In desperation, I capped the rows at 5000 instead of 9999.

Comment: Does the 10,000 include system tables? Every user, type, function etc will have entries.

Comment: Richard - no idea if it does. However, for a single-user, single-table db I don't find it plausible that ~7000 rows could be taken up by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it makes estimated counts until you reach a certain threshold at which point it performs accurate counts (this mechanism subject to change). It will never revoke access or email a user without doing an accurate count first (`SELECT count(*) FROM table1` + `SELECT count(*) FROM table2` etc).

It does not count system tables; it considers all user level tables. Oftentimes people don't realize they have tables that are eating up rows, such as `sessions`, `events` or `logs`.